# SQL Select Statement SubSelect not working correct

Tags: sql, select, join, subquery

I have 2 SQL Select Queries which I need in two seperare columns. The code I have just now does exactly that, but it also gives 2 nulls. Here is my code :

```
Select a.Budget, b.Actual_Income FROM

(Select sum(subscriptions.Bill_Amount) as Budget
From imis.dbo.Name Name INNER JOIN imis.dbo.Subscriptions Subscriptions ON     Name.ID=Subscriptions.ID
Where Member_Type = 'MM' and Name.Status = 'a' and Product_Code = 'Annual' and Subscriptions.Status = 'a') AS a

FULL JOIN

(SELECT sum(Amount * -1) as Actual_Income
FROM   imis.dbo.Name Name INNER JOIN imis.dbo.Trans Trans ON Name.ID=Trans.BT_ID
WHERE  PRODUCT_CODE ='ANNUAL' and Transaction_Date >= '21/10/2013' and Batch_Num <>    'DD131031-3') AS b
 ON a.Budget = b.Actual_Income
```

This Is what It returns

```
Budget         Actual_Income
6367005.00      NULL
NULL            665712.37
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a FULL JOIN. Change it to INNER JOIN.

Check this link for better understanding [SQL JOINS](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

If your results were meant to be as the following:

```
Budget         Actual_Income
6367005.00      665712.37
```

Then you can do subselect or aggregate:

SubSelect:

```
Select (Select sum(subscriptions.Bill_Amount) as Budget
From imis.dbo.Name Name INNER JOIN imis.dbo.Subscriptions Subscriptions ON     Name.ID=Subscriptions.ID
Where Member_Type = 'MM' and Name.Status = 'a' and Product_Code = 'Annual' and Subscriptions.Status = 'a') Budget, 
(SELECT sum(Amount * -1) as Actual_Income
FROM   imis.dbo.Name Name INNER JOIN imis.dbo.Trans Trans ON Name.ID=Trans.BT_ID
WHERE  PRODUCT_CODE ='ANNUAL' and Transaction_Date >= '21/10/2013' and Batch_Num <>    'DD131031-3') as Actual_Income
```

aggregate:

```
Select MAX(a.Budget), MAX(b.Actual_Income) FROM

(Select sum(subscriptions.Bill_Amount) as Budget
From imis.dbo.Name Name INNER JOIN imis.dbo.Subscriptions Subscriptions ON     Name.ID=Subscriptions.ID
Where Member_Type = 'MM' and Name.Status = 'a' and Product_Code = 'Annual' and Subscriptions.Status = 'a') AS a

FULL JOIN

(SELECT sum(Amount * -1) as Actual_Income
FROM   imis.dbo.Name Name INNER JOIN imis.dbo.Trans Trans ON Name.ID=Trans.BT_ID
WHERE  PRODUCT_CODE ='ANNUAL' and Transaction_Date >= '21/10/2013' and Batch_Num <>    'DD131031-3') AS b
```

Comment: when I do an inner join it does not return anything, not even NULL

Comment: What do you expect? Only one row with both results?

Comment: to be honest, Yes. I have only just started learning SQL, appologies.

Comment: I don't like either way, so i will review the full query and post a better solution if i find any.